# Connection aborted when posting with curl

Tags: php, curl, put

I have this situation:
I want to make a PUT request using curl to a form but it keeps retrieving this error: "send failure: connection aborted". Here is the function I use:

```
function PutCurl($url,$parametros_post){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PUT,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: '.strlen($parametros_post)));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parametros_post);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $rerror = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($rerror != ""){
            echo '<h3>'.$rerror.'</h3>';
            return false;
        }
        else
            return $result;

    }
```

I get this error:

While trying to process the request:

PUT /textos-del-anuncio/ HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)
Host: www.somesite.com
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=gkmb7ksi1o82d91rino35ihma3
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Close
X-Forwarded-For: Ip
Via: 1.0 Proxy+ (v4.00 http://www.proxyplus.cz)
Proxy-Authorization: Basic a2F2OjNHd3BiK3J3QiE=

The following error was encountered:

```
* Invalid Request
```

Some aspect of the HTTP Request is invalid. Possible problems:

```
* Missing or unknown request method
* Missing URL
* Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0)
* Request is too large
* Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests
* Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed
```

Then I tried to set Content-Length in the header adding this line to my function:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: '.strlen($parametros_post)));

but then I get a "Send failure: Connection was aborted" error.

Please, someone who can help me. Thanks.

Comment: that's not your real proxy user and password is it?!

Comment: can you post the curl error codes as well?

Comment: I added the error description to the post. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Something being wrong with the request, have you tried doing it like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

So you do not use curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PUT,true); but CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST instead.
I assume your $parametros_post is an associative array like $parametros_post = array('post_field_name' => 'post_field_value');

Comment: Well, no. My $parametros_post is a string that I build like this: 'field_name='.urlencode($field_value); this has worked for me in every POST I have made but not now that the method is PUT.

Comment: When I used curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); it didn't work. I received a reply from the site telling me that I missed the values of the fields.

Comment: Have you tried having the $parametros_post as an associative array while at the same time using curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); and curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data)); as in my example above?

Comment: Yes, I tried it the way you said but I keep getting the same Invalid Request error.